Quantum field theory in high energy physics and condensed matter physics
I read that quantum field theory is also used in the study of condensed matter physics, for instance in the study of quasiparticle where particle numbers may not be conserved. This was a bit surprising to me, since I had thought quantum field theory and other field theories are closely related to the study of high energy physics.
Are there any differences between the quantum field theories used in high energy physics and those in condensed matter physics?

This question is similar to: What are Quantum Field Theories?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
